# How can I create a grid cell map based on two other grid cell map?

Tags: grids-graticules

I have two grid cell maps:

1. Species per grid cell
2. Sample events per grid cell

I need a map which shows the **Species per Sample event per Grid cell**, basically the map that results from dividing Item 1 / Item 2.

Is this possible with DIVA-GIS?  If so, how?